# Java Pattern search with variable string in pattern

Tags: java, regex

Is there any better and compact way to write this code:

```
     String output = "NAME            OS         ACTIVE\n" + 
            "----            --         ------\n" + 
            "ABCD    Windows    Yes\n" + 
            "EFGH    Windows    Yes\n" + 
            "1234    Windows    No\n" + 
            "5678    Windows    Yes\n" + 
            "cv      Windows    Yes";

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(SEARCH_PATTERN, "ABCD"), Pattern.MULTILINE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);

     if (!matcher.find()) {
      throw new ExceptionA();
     }

     pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(SEARCH_PATTERN, "1234"), Pattern.MULTILINE);
     matcher = pattern.matcher(output);

     if (!matcher.find()) {
       throw new ExceptionB();
     }
```

String.matches() doesn't work well on multiline code, so using Pattern is the only option.

Comment: What's it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have keys:

```
String[] keys = { "ABCD", "EFGH", "1234", ... };
```

And you want to throw an exception when one of them is *not* found.
That is hard in regex. Easier would be to form `"(ABCD|EFGH|1234|...)"` and check having handled all (once) by keeping a Set.

Furthermore you want a regular expression, maybe for `"(?m)^ABCD\s+..."`, that is MULTILINE (or embedded `(?m)`), where `^` means begin-of-line.

```
for (String key : keys) {
    String format = String.format(SEARCH_PATTERN, "\\Q" + key + "\\E");
    if (!output.matches("(?ms).*" + format + ".*")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing key: " + key);
    }
}
```

`String.matches` unfortunately considers the entire string, hence for a *find* pattern, that pattern must be added `.*` at both sides.

- `(?m)` for multiline (`^` and `$` line based)
- `(?s)` for single-dot (`.` can also be a newline character)
- `\Q`...`\E` is quoted text without regex operators: `.` just meaning period.

Streams might exploit parallelism with many keys. However as not finding (the early stop criterion) is the longest thread, that might merely be faster by a factor of the number of used threads.

Comment: This works wonderfully!! I can't understand the use of \Q and \E. Please explain.

Comment: Should a substring, you want to match against, contain special characters that are regex commands, like `. * + ? [ (` then placing them between those Quote and End-quote characters allows those special characters not being interpreted as regex.